# Returning the value in the bottom row of a column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to a cell to just print what the last cell in a column. If I were to have the column starting on row 17,

```
1
3
5
```

I want it to print five, but if I updated the list to

```
1
3
5
7
```

I want it to print 7, but I know nothing about the functions of spreadsheets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a constant to represent "last row of a column" in Google Spreadsheet?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95538/is-there-a-constant-to-represent-last-row-of-a-column-in-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Formula

```
=INDEX(A17:A,COUNT(A17:A))
```

## Explanation

Assuming that the data is on the `column A`, that it only has numbers, and that there are not blank cells between two cells with numbers, `COUNT(A17:A)` will return the count of cells having a number and it will be the index of the last cell with a number on `column A`. Index will return the value of the last cell that has a number in `column A`.

## NOTES

- If the values are `TEXT` instead of `NUMBER` use `COUNTA` instead of `COUNT`
- If the values are mixed, `TEXT` and other type like `NUMBER` / `DATE` / `TIME` / `DURATION` , instead of the above formula use

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A17:A, MAX(IF(ISBLANK(A17:A),,ROW(A17:A)))))
  ```

  or

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A17:A, MAX(IF(LEN(A17:A),ROW(A17:A),)))))
  ```

## See also

- [Is there a constant to represent "last row of a column" in Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95538/is-there-a-constant-to-represent-last-row-of-a-column-in-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: It didn't quite work because my data doesn't start until row 17 in my document, but after that it is a continuous list. Is there a way to set it to start there?

Comment: I edited your question and my answer.

Comment: Also, if the values are not numbers, you will need to use `COUNTA` not `COUNT`.

Comment: @JamesFaix Thanks. I updated my answer :)